# SQL Server: Multiple Rows to Multiple Columns by Joining tables with CASE:

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have this query which gives me perfect result:

```
select vst_int_id,
max(case when seq = 1 then chg_dtl_int_id end) chg1,
max(case when seq = 2 then chg_dtl_int_id end) chg2,
max(case when seq = 3 then chg_dtl_int_id end) chg3,
max(case when seq = 4 then chg_dtl_int_id end) chg4,
max(case when seq = 5 then chg_dtl_int_id end) chg5
from (
       select c.vst_int_id, c.chg_dtl_int_id,   
       row_number() over(partition by c.vst_int_id order by chg_dtl_int_id) seq

       from CHARGE_DETAIL c
       inner join PAT_VISIT b ON b.vst_int_id = c.vst_int_id
       where c.vst_int_id = '14568778'
)d
group by vst_int_id
```

Result:

```
vst_int_id  |     chg1   |  chg2     |    chg3   |  chg4    |     chg5
14568778    |    23340   |  2334     |    2334   |   2490   |     2110
```

I would like to bring in a field from PAT_VISIT table, for example:

Prefered Result:

```
vst_int_id  |   chg1|    chg2   |   chg3     |   chg4   |  chg5 | Patient_ID
14568778    |  23340|    2334   |   4534     | 2490     | 2110  | 0012456
```

I have joined `Charge_Detail` table to `PAT_VISIT` table but when I try to bring the `Patient_ID` field from `PAT_VISIT` table, it will not show up.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this (I assume Patient_Id is the exact column name referring id of the patient):

```
select vst_int_id,
max(case when seq = 1 then d.chg_dtl_int_id end) chg1,
max(case when seq = 2 then d.chg_dtl_int_id end) chg2,
max(case when seq = 3 then d.chg_dtl_int_id end) chg3,
max(case when seq = 4 then d.chg_dtl_int_id end) chg4,
max(case when seq = 5 then d.chg_dtl_int_id end) chg5,
p.Patient_ID
from (
       select c.vst_int_id, c.chg_dtl_int_id,   
       row_number() over(partition by c.vst_int_id order by chg_dtl_int_id) seq
       from CHARGE_DETAIL c
       where c.vst_int_id = '14568778'
) d
inner join PAT_VISIT p ON p.vst_int_id = d.vst_int_id
group by d.vst_int_id, p.Patient_ID
```

Comment: Yes Patient_Id is the exact column name referring id of the patient.  I tried the above but it gave me Ambiguous column name 'vst_int_id' error and I tried grouping Patient_ID followed by d.vst_int_id and still gives me error. Then I changed select vst_int_id to d.vst_int_id and it gave me null result

Comment: I kept entering the wrong vst_int_id number so it gave me a null result. Your solution actually worked. Thank you so much!!!!